# Remote GDB disconnects whenever I press control + c

Tags: gdb, embedded, remote-debugging, openocd

I am remote debugging a Stellaris Launchpad. I use OpenOCD to connect to the stellaris and then connect GDB to the server provided by openOCD. I use Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0-dev-00002-g79fdeb3 (2015-07-09-23:28). GDB is the one from arm-gcc-none-eabi, the 4_9-2015q1 release.
I invoke openOCD like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/openocd --file \
/usr/local/share/openocd/scripts/board/ek-lm4f120xl.cfg \
>> openocdLog.txt 2>&1 &
```

And then GDB like this:

```
arm-none-eabi-gdb proj//debug/exec -x gdb//gdb.script
```

gdb/gdb.script contains:

```
set remotetimeout 10000
target extended-remote :3333
monitor reset halt
load
monitor reset init
```

The problem is that whenever I hit control+c GDB disconnects. Normally this would halt the remote, but GDB just disconnects:

```
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
^CError detected on fd 6
Remote communication error.  Target disconnected.: Interrupted system call.
(gdb)
```

OpenOCD has the following things to say, this one while GDB is launching:

```
Warn : keep_alive() was not invoked in the 1000ms timelimit. GDB alive packet not sent! (1258). Workaround: increase "set remotetimeout" in GDB
```

Which is weird, considering the gdb/gdb.script file forces remotetimeout to an insanly large number.

And when pressing control+c openOCD says:

```
Debug: 2602 5089 hla_interface.c:119 hl_interface_quit(): hl_interface_quit
```

So, how do I resolve this? How can I make GDB halt the remote instead of disconnecting when pressing control+c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was OpenOCD being too bleeding edge. I had issues with 0.6.1, but version 0.7.0 of OpenOCD works great.

Comment: Still having this issue on OpenOCD 0.9.0 with GDB 7.8.0. Can you link to an OpenOCD bug report?

Comment: I did not create one, because I was unable to gather enough information to know wether or not the bug is actually in OpenOCD or if it is in GDB.

Comment: Still having this issue on OpenOCD 0.10.0 with GDB 7.12.1.20170215.